# Having to press log out twice to actually destory my user's session - react + express

Tags: reactjs, express, session-cookies

I've got a react front end that performs some actions. The relevant axios requests look like so:

```
    const login = async () => {
        await Axios.post('http://localhost:8000/login', {
            username: username,
            password: password,
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log("login response: ", response);
            window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/";
        }).catch(err => {
            alert(err.response.data);
        });
    };

    // run on first render to see if user session is still active - remove console log later
    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:8000/isLoggedIn").then((response) => {
            console.log("isLoggedIn resonse: ", response);
            if (response.data.loggedIn === true) {
                setLoginStatus(`Logged in as ${response.data.user}`);
            }
        })
    }, [])


    const Logout = async () => {
        try {
            await Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/logout').then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/login";
            }).catch(err => {
                alert(err);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error)
        }
    };
```

I keep having to press log out twice to actually log my user out. The logout route runs before the "isLoggedIn" route, according to my network tab. And it's successful, too. Here are the isLoggedIn and logout routes in my express backend:

```
export function isLoggedIn( req: any, res: any) {
    if (req.session.user) {
        // if our session already has a user, send true to the frontend
        // frontend runs this get login on first render, so will have user data if cookie has not expired.
        res.send({loggedIn: true, user: req.session.user})
    } else {
        res.send({loggedIn: false});
    }
}

export function logout(req: any, res: any) {
    if (req.session) {
        req.session.destroy( (err: any) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(400).send('Unable to log out');
            } else {
                res.send("Logout successful");
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.end();
    }
}
```

I'm getting a successful logout. I just cannot figure out why I need to hit the logout button twice on the frontend to actually destroy the session and log the user out? Is there something timing related that I may be missing here?